# Reorder List of strings based on enclosed timestamp

Tags: c#

Using C# WinForms. I have Two Lists:

**1st List:** Strings are in order by timestamps which is within the brackets.

```
List<string> lst1 = new List<string>();
//TimeStamps Between brackets
lst1.Add("Attack(1:05)");
lst1.Add("MoveUp(1:35)");
lst1.Add("MoveDown(1:48)");
lst1.Add("MoveLeft(2:15)");
lst1.Add("MoveDown(2:24)");
lst1.Add("MoveUp(2:50)");
lst1.Add("MoveLeft(3:04)");
lst1.Add("MoveUp(5:15)");
lst1.Add("MoveLeft(7:30)");
//ETC.
```

**2nd List:** Again! Strings are in order by timestamps which is within the brackets.

```
List<string> lst2 = new List<string>();
//TimeStamps Between brackets
lst2.Add("Armor Lvl1(0:04)");
lst2.Add("Loom(0:10)");
lst2.Add("Balistics(4:42)");
lst2.Add("Mail Armor(5:02)");
lst2.Add("Ring(6:12)");
lst2.Add("Fire Holes(8:44)");
lst2.Add("Attack Lvl2(10:13)");
lst2.Add("Defence Lvl1(12:33)");
lst2.Add("Defence Lvl2(20:11)");
//ETC.
```

Then, We combine both lists into a new list using: `lst1.AddRange(lst2);` Here is the output:

```
//output of lst1 after the combination
//Armor Lvl1(0:04)
//Loom(0:10)
//Balistics(4:42)
//Mail Armor(5:02)
//Ring(6:12)
//Fire Holes(8:44)
//Attack Lvl2(10:13)
//Defence Lvl1(12:33)
//Defence Lvl2(20:11)
//Attack(1:05)
//MoveUp(1:35)
//MoveDown(1:48)
//MoveLeft(2:15)
//MoveDown(2:24)
//MoveUp(2:50)
//MoveLeft(3:04)
//MoveUp(5:15)
//MoveLeft(7:30)
```

Now I need to reorder this combined list by timestamps so the output looks like:

```
//output of lst1 in order by timestamp
Armor Lvl1(0:04)
Loom(0:10)
Attack(1:05)
MoveUp(1:35)
MoveDown(1:48)
MoveLeft(2:15)
MoveDown(2:24)
MoveUp(2:50)
MoveLeft(3:04)
Balistics(4:42)
Mail Armor(5:02)
MoveUp(5:15)
Ring(6:12)
MoveLeft(7:30)
Fire Holes(8:44)
Attack Lvl2(10:13)
Defence Lvl1(12:33)
Defence Lvl2(20:11)
```

Any clue how to achieve this order?

Some hints:

To extract the timestamp from the string:

```
Regex.Match("Defence Lvl2(20:11)", @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Looks like you would have to parse the content, and then sort based on the timestamp. So maybe bring an extra datastructure in to contain the data (text & timestamp) and then do the sorting based on that

Comment: @OlivierRogier I have never done such thing like this before but probably an example could be of greater help.  In the hint section, I put a code to extract what is between brackets e.g. 20:11

Comment: @OlivierRogier Yes, first and second list are both in order. The combination of the two is not. Only the combination that needs ordering.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Thank you brother! I'm not as knowledgeable as you are in c# though 7 years I started just 3 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without regex nor linq.

Using only the hands old fashioned.

```
    static void Test()
    {
      List<string> list = new List<string>();
      list.Add("Armor Lvl1(0:04)");
      list.Add("Loom(0:10)");
      list.Add("Balistics(4:42)");
      list.Add("Mail Armor(5:02)");
      list.Add("Ring(6:12)");
      list.Add("Fire Holes(8:44)");
      list.Add("Attack Lvl2(10:13)");
      list.Add("Defence Lvl1(12:33)");
      list.Add("Defence Lvl2(20:11)");
      list.Add("Attack(1:05)");
      list.Add("MoveUp(1:35)");
      list.Add("MoveDown(1:48)");
      list.Add("MoveLeft(2:15)");
      list.Add("MoveDown(2:24)");
      list.Add("MoveUp(2:50)");
      list.Add("MoveLeft(3:04)");
      list.Add("MoveUp(5:15)");
      list.Add("MoveLeft(7:30)");
      foreach ( var item in SortTheListByTime(list) )
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

```
    static List<string> SortTheListByTime(List<string> list)
    {
      var result = new List<string>();
      var items = new SortedDictionary<TimeSpan, string>();
      foreach ( string item in list )
      {
        int index;
        int posColon = item.IndexOf(':');
        if ( posColon == -1 ) continue;
        int posStart = -1;
        for ( index = posColon - 1; index >= 0; index-- )
          if (item[index] == '(')
          {
            posStart = index + 1;
            break;
          }
        if ( posStart == -1 ) continue;
        int posEnd = -1;
        for ( index = posColon + 1; index < item.Length; index++ )
          if ( item[index] == ')' )
          {
            posEnd = index - 1;
            break;
          }
        if ( posEnd == -1 ) continue;
        string strTime = item.Substring(posStart, item.Length - posEnd + 2);
        if ( TimeSpan.TryParse(strTime, out var time) )
          if ( !items.ContainsKey(time) )
            items.Add(time, item);
      }
      result.AddRange(items.Values);
      return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the second time in the row today. I will give this a go.

Comment: there is a little problem with the function `System.ArgumentException: 'An entry with the same key already exists.'` I don't  mind having duplicate items.

Comment: Answer updated. The algorithm assumes that in case of any error in the string format or duplicated, the item is ignored.

Comment: Stellar logic! Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple for your problem.

If you used `OrderBy` of linq and then parse your string that are in between round brackets to `TimeSpan` then things will be simple like

```
var result = list.OrderBy(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x.Split('(', ')')[1])).ToList();
```

If you print this result to console then output will be

```
result.ForEach(x => {
    Console.WriteLine(x);
});

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: oh f#*% me!!  I love one lined sweat-less solutions. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear and please accept answer if possible :)

Answer (score -1):

The [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) type does not enforcing sorting, and will therefore be "sorted" according to insertion ordering. If these timestamps are when objects were inserted, then it's perfectly reasonable that they'll be sorted accordingly.

To implement sorting, geing strings, you'll need to write your own comparison method and call [`List.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8) while passing this method in either as a delegate `IComparison` or within a class implementing `IComparer`.

For reasons such as this, I strongly recommend that you consider whether these should be objects rather than strings, as having the `string Name` and `TimeSpan Timestamp` split into two fields will make sorting a simple matter of using `x => x.Timestamp` rather than needing to extract the timestamp via Regex (`\([0-9]{1-2}:[0-9]{2}\)`)or the like.